# HTML5 Video - Should the poster image disappear too soon before showing the video?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I have a full width background video, see [www.sparkengine.tv](http://www.sparkengine.tv) - not everything is finished yet. But the problem is some users are seeing the poster image, then it disappears just before the video is loaded, doesn't look very seamless. I imagined making it look like the still poster image just starts moving.

I've seen other sites without this issue...

Is this normal? Is there a fix?

Henry

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

1. Set the vids autoplay attr to false.
2. Add script:

   Var vid = document.getElementById("bgVid");
   vid.oncanplay = vid.play();

Or, alternatively, you could try:

```
vid.oncanplaythrough = vid.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i could consider would make something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="video-container" style="position:relative; overflow:auto">
 <img src="poster.jpg" id="videoposter" width=600 style="position:absolute; z-index:2" />
 <video src="video.mp4" poster="poster.jpg" style="width:600px; height:400px"></video>
</div>

<a href="#" id="videoplay">Play the video</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var video = document.getElementById('videoelement');

var btn_play = document.getElementById('videoplay');
btn_play.onclick = function() {
 video.currentTime = 0;
 video.play();
};

video.onloadeddata = function() {
 document.getElementById('videoposter').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's normal for the poster image to disappear slightly before the video starts playing. The way I would solve this is by adding an image in front of the video. After you tell the video to start playing, and wait for the playing event on the video element to be fired. Then hide (or even quickly fade out) the image.

Something like this:

```
var playedBefore=false,myvideo=document.getElementById('myvideo')
myvideo.addEventListener('playing',
    function(){
        if(!playedBefore){
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('myposter').style.display='none';
            },100);// Just a little extra time.
        }
        playedBefore=true;
    });
myvideo.play();
```

You can mess with the events and function calls at http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html.

Another thing to do would be to call the `load()` method on the video a while before you want it to play so that it's ready to play by the time you call the `play()` function.

Here's a JSFiddle that does all of this plus fades the poster out: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/CM4dg/